# How to prevent divs from going underneath floated divs

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone from StackOverflow !

**How can I prevent divs from going underneath floated divs  ?**

```css
body {
  /* ======================== block ======================== */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 19%;
  margin-right: 19%;
  /* ======================== colors ======================= */
  background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
  /* ======================================================= */
}

div {
  /* ======================== block ======================== */
  margin: 0.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* ======================== colors ======================= */
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* ======================================================= */
}

#menu {
  /* ======================== block ======================== */
  display: table;
  float: left;
  /* ======================================================= */
}

#menu a {
  /* ======================== block ======================== */
  display: block;
  /* ======================================================= */
}

#footer {
  /* ======================== block ======================== */
  clear: both;
  /* ======================================================= */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Info-Bulle</title>
  <link href='includes/css/index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>

<body>

  <div id='header'>
    <span id='logo'>Info-Bulle</span>
    <span id='catch'>Club d'entraide informatique pour les séniors</span>
  </div>

  <div id='menu'>
    <a href=''><img src='includes/img/house.png' /></a>
    <a href=''><img src='includes/img/journal.png' /></a>
    <a href=''><img src='includes/img/dictionary.png' /></a>
    <a href=''><img src='includes/img/envelope.png' /></a>
    <a href=''><img src='includes/img/question.png' /></a>
    <a href=''><img src='includes/img/open-book.png' /></a>
  </div>
  <div class='p'>
    Bienvenue(s) sur le club d'entraide informatique pour s&eacute;niors appel&eacute; Info-Bulle !
    </br>
    Besoin d'aide ?
    </br>
    Envie d'apprendre l'informatique ? C'est &agrave; ca que sert Info-Bulle.
    </br>
    Si vous ne savez pas comment utiliser ce site, veuillez consulter le <a href=''>manuel d'utilisation</a>.
  </div>


  <div id='footer'>
    Mis en place par le CCAS de M&acirc;con et d&eacute;vellop&eacute; par Sanchez Tanguy.
    </br>
    Toutes les ic&ocirc;nes viennent de <a href='https://www.flaticon.com/'>Flaticon.com</a>.
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkiPa.png)

As shown in the image above, my divs are automatically going underneath the floated one. I tried to use margins on the floated div but it doesn't seem to be the best solution for later uses.

Do you have any other solution rather than using a "margin-right on the menu" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's time to use a better way to handle your layout. Here is a solution with flexbox:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 19% 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

div {
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id='header'>
  <span id='logo'>Info-Bulle</span>
  <span id='catch'>Club d'entraide informatique pour les séniors</span>
</div>
<section class="content">
  <div id='menu'>
    <a href=''><img src='https://lorempixel.com/50/50/'></a>
    <a href=''><img src='https://lorempixel.com/40/50/'></a>
    <a href=''><img src='https://lorempixel.com/50/50/'></a>
    <a href=''><img src='https://lorempixel.com/50/40/'></a>
    <a href=''><img src='https://lorempixel.com/50/50/'></a>
    <a href=''><img src='https://lorempixel.com/50/70/'></a>
  </div>
  <div class='p'>
    Bienvenue(s) sur le club d'entraide informatique pour s&eacute;niors appel&eacute; Info-Bulle !
    <br> Besoin d'aide ?
    <br> Envie d'apprendre l'informatique ? C'est &agrave; ca que sert Info-Bulle.
    <br> Si vous ne savez pas comment utiliser ce site, veuillez consulter le <a href=''>manuel d'utilisation</a>.
  </div>
</section>


<div id='footer'>
  Mis en place par le CCAS de M&acirc;con et d&eacute;vellop&eacute; par Sanchez Tanguy.
  <br> Toutes les ic&ocirc;nes viennent de <a href='https://www.flaticon.com/'>Flaticon.com</a>.
</div>
```

Comment: Never heard of that before, I'm gonna give it a try. I'm gonna mark my question as answered when I will have your code snipped all figured out. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SanchezTanguy and here is a good tuto to start with : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: There is so much things I'm confused ha ha.

Comment: @SanchezTanguy you can also check bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/. it also rely on flex ;) .. by the way it's not the only technique but the float technique is a way too old and has a lot of drawbacks ... so i think it's better to spend time to learn the new stuffs and then you will easily code any layout

Comment: I wanted to mark my question as 'answered' but I noticed something with that solution that is not what I wanted.
This : `flex-basis: 78%;` I don't wanna to define any size. Because I don't know on which device my website is gonna be displayed. Is there any solution more 'responsive' with flex ?

Comment: @SanchezTanguy of course there is always a solution with flex :) i simply went with a fast one based on your code .. i updated my answer you can have a look

Comment: I want to keep my html version, but I'll start from there, thanks for the code :)